# Add onclick Event to a jQuery.each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to Javascript and jQuery. This is my JSON file. I want to add a jQuery onclick event to a jQuery.each(). Here is my code.

```js
{
  "1": [{
    "RequestId": "1",
    "CustomerId": "1",
    "RequestCharge": "100.00",
    "Trade": ""

  }],
  "2": [{
    "RequestId": "1",
    "CustomerId": "1",
    "RequestCharge": "100.00",
    "Trade": ""
  }],
  "3": [{
    "RequestId": "1",
    "CustomerId": "1",
    "RequestCharge": "50.00",
    "Trade": ""
  }]
}
```

The code below works well

```
 $.each(output, function(i) {                   
    var tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + output[i][0].RequestId + "-"  +"</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + output[i][0].CustomerId + "-" + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + output[i][0].RequestCharge + "</td>");
    $("#whad").append(tr);
    });
```

But i want to add a click function with each giving value of i.
This is my code below but i is undefined.

```
$.each(output, function(i) {                    
        var tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + output[i][0].RequestId + "-"  +"</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + output[i][0].CustomerId + "-" + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + output[i][0].RequestCharge + "</td>");
        $("#whad").append(tr).click(function() {
            console.log("This is the value of i clicked: " + this.i)
        });
        });
```

Here is my html.

```
    <table id = "whad"> </table>
```

I need this.i to return a value of the one clicked.

Comment: What do you want to extract?

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: RequestId, CustomerId and RequestCharge

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i believe i have edited my question to be clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the json to an object:

`var obj = JSON.parse(text);`

and then retrieve the values from the object:

`obj["1"][0].RequestId`

if you want to display them all, you need to iterate through the array and print the values you want:

```
for (var i = 0; i<output.length; i++) {
    $("#YOURDIV").append("Request id: " + obj[i][0].RequestId);
    $("#YOURDIV").append("Customer id: " + obj[i][0].CustomerId);
    $("#YOURDIV").append("Request Charge : " + obj[i][0].RequestCharge);
}
```

Comment: It worked. the first RequestId is displayed. But how can i display all the RequestId in the JSON file?

Comment: just loop through all the elements on the array :)

Comment: I have edited my question. any idea why the code is not working?

Comment: Your edited code is not working. my 3 divs are blank.